# Handlebars not rendering unless data is reassigned to another variable

Tags: handlebars.js

My Handlebars `render()` function returns an empty string unless the data from my AJAX response is assigned to a new variable. I can work around this, but I am curious if I have done something wrong which caused it.

The offending code in question:

```js
// Get the list of rooms from the server
$.ajax({
    url: "/rooms",
    method: "GET",
    statusCode: {
        200: (res) => {
            // Must reassign res to another variable in order to render
            const rooms = res;
            $("#room-list").html(render({rooms}));
        },
    },
});
```

It should also be noted that `res === rooms` returns `true`.

Where I am getting the template:

```js
const template = $("#room-item-template").html();
const render = Handlebars.compile(template);
```

And, finally, the HTML template itself:

```html
<template id="room-item-template">
    \{{#each rooms}}
    <article class="room-item" id="\{{_id}}">
        <a href="/chat?room=\{{_id}}">
            <button class="room-btn">
                <h3>\{{name}}</h3>
                <p>\{{users.length}} / \{{capacity}}</p>
            </button>
        </a>

        <a href="/rooms/config/\{{_id}}">
            <button class="room-config-btn">Configure Room</button>
        </a>
    </article>
    \{{/each}}
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How were you passing `res` to the render function?
It should have been be as follows.

```
$("#room-list").html(render({ rooms: res }))
```

Comment: That makes more sense. I had simply forgotten that the variable name must be the same as that on the template. Thanks for the help.